# Java: Deleting node from linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, java.util.scanner, nodes, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to delete a node in a linked list in java, but I keep getting a NullPointerException when attempting to use my deletenode() method.

```
I get the following error trace:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at linkedlist.LinkedList.deletenode(LinkedList.java:44)
at linkedlist.LinkedList.main(LinkedList.java:69)
/Users/carsongedeus/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: 
Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)


package linkedlist;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author carsongedeus
 */

class Node {

    int data;
    Node next;

    Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class LinkedList {

    Node head;
    Node temp;
```

Inserting at the head of the list.

```
    public Node insertnode(int data) {

        if(head == null) {
            head = new Node(data);
        } else {
            temp = new Node(data);
            temp.next = head;
            head = temp;
        }
        return head;
    }
```

Delete method is giving a NULLPointerException after the user types in specified integer within a node of the linked list.

```
    public void deletenode(int data) {

        Node trace;
        Node del;

        for(trace = head; trace != null; trace = trace.next) {

            if(trace.next.data == data) {
                del = trace.next;
                trace = trace.next.next;
                del.next = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Printer

```
    public void printer() {
        System.out.println(head.data);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList linkedlist = new LinkedList();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;

        for(int i = 0; i < (n = (int)(Math.random()*100+1)); i++) {
            linkedlist.insertnode((int)(Math.random()*100+1));
            linkedlist.printer();
        }

        System.out.println("Delete something: ");
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        linkedlist.deletenode(input);

        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            linkedlist.printer();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please upload you error trace?

Comment: your delete node method will have npe if head = null (no nodes in list) or if have one node in list. should be checking if current element trace.data == data not trace.next.data == data

Comment: replace `trace.next.data==data` with `trace.data==data`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void deletenode(int data) {
    if (head != null && head.data == data) {
        head = head.next; // delete head
        return;
    }
    Node prev = null;
    Node cur = head;
    while (cur != null && cur.data != data) {
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur.next;
    }
    prev.next = cur.next; // delete cur
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your approach, the node to be deleted is `trace.next` (which you're referring to as `del`). This mean's that `trace`'s `next` pointer needs to be updated to `trace.next.next`, effectively "skipping over" the node to be deleted (`trace.next`). This looks like: `trace.next = trace.next.next`

What you're doing instead is modifying `trace` itself by setting it to `trace.next.next`. I understand this is to make the iteration work properly, but mucks up the rest of your code, since you've lost the pointer to the node you need to update. If we modify `trace.next`, the loop will take care of advancing the pointer properly when it runs `trace = trace.next` at its conclusion.

In Java object with no more references pointing to it is removed from the computer's memory -- this process is called garbage collection. Since we've already modified `trace.next` at this point, there are no further references to the node to be deleted spare the `del` variable you made. Once that variable goes out of scope at the conclusion of this function, the node will be garbage collected with no further action on your part. You don't even really need the del variable at all; as soon as we lose the reference to the old `trace.next` by updating (skipping over) it, no further references exist to that Node and the garbage collector will cull it.

Taking all of this into account, your code simply becomes:

```
public void deletenode(int data) {

    Node trace;

    for(trace = head; trace != null; trace = trace.next) {

        if(trace.next.data == data) {
            trace.next = trace.next.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare a temp field: use a local variable instead:

```
public Node insertnode(int data) {

    if(head == null) {
        head = new Node(data);
    } else {
        Node temp = new Node(data);
        temp.next = head;
        head = temp;
    }
    return head;
}
```

To answer your question, you test if trace is not null, and then try to access trace.next.data without testing trace.next.

Try something like this:

```
public void deletenode(int data) {

    Node prev = null;

    for(Node trace = head; trace != null; trace = trace.next) {

        if(trace.data == data) {
            if (prev == null) {
                head = trace.next;
            } else {
                prev.next = trace.next;
            }
        } else {
            prev = trace;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach to the problem is wrong. Please find the appropriate way of handling linked list question.

LinkedListNode class:

```
class LinkedListNode {
    int data;
    LinkedListNode next;
    LinkedListNode(int data) {
        this.data= data;
        this.next=null;
    }
}
```

Insertion at the begining:

```
 LinkedListNode insertNodeAtBegining(LinkedListNode head, int val) {
        LinkedListNode temp= head;
        head= new LinkedListNode(val);
        head.next=temp;
        return head;
    }
```

Deleting a node:

```
LinkedListNode deleteNode(LinkedListNode head, LinkedListNode node) {
    if(head==null) {
        return head;
    }
    if(head.data==node.data) {
        return head.next;
    }

    LinkedListNode temp=head;
    while(temp.next!=null) {
        if(temp.next.data==node.data) {
            temp.next=temp.next.next;
        }
        temp=temp.next;
    }
    return head;
}
```